# Page Public Content Access Rate Limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rate-limiting

For the most part, an application has To go through an *App review* to get permission to extract data from the Facebook Graph API.

If an application receives a *Page Public Content Access* permission in Graph API and that permission is used to gather public data from a select number of pages, how is the rate limit calculated?

As far as i have understood there are two types of rate limits in Graph API,

- User Rate limit
- Page Rate limit

Which one is used when utilizing a *Page Public Content Access* to read data from public pages? This is not specifically stated anywhere in the documentation and is quite crucial for our possibility to implement our solution.

Thank you for your help.
Cheers Valentin Ibanez

Comment: usually rate limits are per token, so in that case it should be a user rate limit.